# Adding to JSON in Python and converting to an object

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON array shown below.

```
[
    "3D3iAR9M4HDETajfD79gs9BM8qhMSq5izX", 
    "35xfg4UnpEJeHDo55HNwJbr1V3G1ddCuVA"
]
```

I would like to add a value in the form of the string (self.tx_amount_5) so I get a JSON OBJECT something like this:

```
{
    "3D3iAR9M4HDETajfD79gs9BM8qhMSq5izX" : 100000
    "35xfg4UnpEJeHDo55HNwJbr1V3G1ddCuVA" : 100000
}
```

The part of code that has generated the first JSON array is:

```
r = requests.get('http://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/A/balance')
    balance = r.json()['balance']

    with open("Entries#x1.csv") as f,open("winningnumbers.csv") as nums:
        nums = set(imap(str.rstrip, nums))
        r = csv.reader(f)
        results = defaultdict(list)
        for row in r:
            results[sum(n in nums for n in islice(row, 1, None))].append(row[0])

    self.number_matched_0 = results[0]
    self.number_matched_1 = results[1]
    self.number_matched_2 = results[2]
    self.number_matched_3 = results[3]
    self.number_matched_4 = results[4]
    self.number_matched_5 = results[5]

    self.number_matched_5_json = json.dumps(self.number_matched_5, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)

    print(self.number_matched_5_json)

    if len(self.number_matched_3) == 0:
        print('Nobody matched 3 numbers')
    else:
        self.tx_amount_3 = int((balance*0.001)/ len(self.number_matched_3))

    if len(self.number_matched_4) == 0:
        print('Nobody matched 4 numbers')
    else:
        self.tx_amount_4 = int((balance*0.1)/ len(self.number_matched_4))

    if len(self.number_matched_5) == 0:
        print('Nobody matched 3 numbers')
    else:
        self.tx_amount_5 = int((balance*0.4)/ len(self.number_matched_5))
```

Comment: Can you specify what the problem is?

Comment: I essentially want to turn the first JSON array into the second JSON object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can create the dictionary like this:

```
import json

s="""[
      "3D3iAR9M4HDETajfD79gs9BM8qhMSq5izX", 
      "35xfg4UnpEJeHDo55HNwJbr1V3G1ddCuVA"
]"""

d = {el: self.tx_amount_5 for el in json.loads(s)}
print(d)
```

which produces

```
{'3D3iAR9M4HDETajfD79gs9BM8qhMSq5izX': 100000,
 '35xfg4UnpEJeHDo55HNwJbr1V3G1ddCuVA': 100000}
```

Comment: Please note that it's overkill to create a json and then parse it again. If it is possible to alter the code, create the dictionary alongside the json. BTW, the code has a cut&paste error in the error message for 5 numbers